# one step Bugzilla installation

Tags: installation, bugzilla

I'm looking into installing Bugzilla either on a Windows or Linux box.  Bugzilla requires a bunch of packages (apache, sql, mail sending?).  Does anyone know of a pre-packaged installer which includes most common options or a linux virtual machine image?

Answer (score 1):

Unofficial [Windows installers](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32InstallPackages) have just been released for Bugzilla.

Answer (score 1):

Grab an image from [Turnkey](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/bugzilla), they have a Bugzilla image that you can put on an unused computer or run in a VM.  They have a lot of pre-built images available.

Answer (score 1):

## Install Ubuntu Desktop/Server 10.10

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bugzilla3
http://localhost/bugzilla3
```

## Administer the MySQL database?:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

...all too easy my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to go with a hosted solution like [devZing.com](http://devzing.com). We've got hosted Bugzilla & Subversion as a package.